# Fundamental Group of Polygon

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

I have a question. I am trying to calculate $\pi _{1}(X)$ where $X$ is a polygon as you see in the picture such that $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ two punctures by identifying edges.

[image]

Here is my **idea**. I think, if I identify edges I will have $2-$Sphere with two punctured points. One point punctured sphere homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, then by using the second one, it is homotopy equivalent to $S^{1}$. And finally, I will have $\pi _{1}(X)=\mathbb{Z}$. Am I right?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, the space is homeomorphic to a sphere minus two points, which has fundamental group $\mathbb Z$ by your argument.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Except that for spaces I think it is more common to use the phrase "homotopy equivalent" rather than the word "homotopic" (which is reserved for two mappings).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you for the correction.